# Implementing user defined display order UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

i have a list of products that are being displayed in particular order. store admin can reassign the display order, by moving the "hot" items to the top of the list. what's the best way of implementing the admin functionality **UI** [asp.net C#]? Products table has a [displayOrder(int)] filed which determines the display order.

i'm looking for something intuitive and simple.

thank you.

p.s. i guess i didn't make myself clear, i'm looking for UI advice more than anything.

SOLUTION: ReorderList worked out great, this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/justinsaraceno/archive/2008/02/22/reorderlist-with-objectdatasource.aspx) helped too. Also, make sure OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}" in your DataSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using AJAX you could implement a Reoder list control you can find more information here http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ReorderList/ReorderList.aspx

Mauro

[http://www.brantas.co.uk](http://www.brantas.co.uk/)

Answer (score 2):

You need a Rank field for each product (which could also be the DisplayOrder field).
When the administrator ups or downs a product, update the rank value.
When you need to list the products, do a select query which sorts in DESC order of rank.

Answer (score 0):

i'm implementing that using the 'Order' column/property where people input numbers like 10, 20, 30 (i have ascending ordering). i have a list of items with text boxes to input order, and an 'apply order' button that saves new values to the database and reorders/reloads items on the page with the new ordering applied.

i don't forbid inputting the same value for two items, i sort them by name as a second sort parameter, or leave it to the database to sort it at will if it doesn't matter much. i believe it's understandable enough to put it that way, it seems like an ordered list which everybody understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the database, add an IsHot column. Then sort by IsHot and DisplayOrder (in that order). This will keep the products in the correct order and the "hot" products will bubble up to the top.